# Codeigniter - AJAX close connection and run php script in background

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am trying to write a ajax to start the php file execution in background for long time in codeigniter.
I have written code to flush the output to ajax and then want to execute rest of code in background.
Code written below is working fine on localhost but not on actual server
I have disabled the gzip compression also but no luck
Hope you can help me out with this.

`<?php
    ignore_user_abort(true);
    ob_start();
    echo "show something to user";
    session_write_close();
    header("Content-Encoding: none");
    header("Content-Length: ".ob_get_length());
    header("Connection: close");
    ob_end_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(5);
    // start rest of background process in php
?>`

Comment: You may need to `ini_set()` any relevant PHP timeouts. Secondly, it may be better to 'queue' the operation via cronjob and let the user know once finished.